# interfacing Python, C, and Fortran

Tags: python, c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I've written a C extension for python (using the Python/C API) that builds with distutils and works nicely.  Now I want to add to that C code a wrapper for some Fortran routines. The end result I'm looking for is a python function that calls a C function that calls a Fortran function.

Is this possible?  I can successfully call C from Python, and Fortran from C, but I'm having trouble combining all three.  Any ideas? Thanks!

---

EDITED
Here is a more detailed example of the structure I want:

Suppose I have a Fortran routine called fortranfunc.f90, and a C code called cfunc.c which has the following form:

```
#include <Python.h> 
#include<numpy/arrayobject.h> 

static PyObject *cfunc(PyObject *self, PyObject *args); 
extern double fortranfunc_(double*);  

static PyObject *cfunc(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{       
     /* a bunch of C code here to calculate the double x */

      y = fortranfunc_(&x);   //now call the fortran function

     /* now finish up using the value of y returned by the fortran function */
}       

static PyMethodDef cfunc_methods[] = {{"cfunc", cfunc, METH_VARARGS, NULL},{NULL}};

void initcfunc(void)
{
      Py_InitModule("cfunc", cfunc_methods);
      import_array();
}
```

I'm trying to build it with a setup.py file like this one:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import numpy as np

module1 = Extension('cfunc', sources = ['cfunc.c'])

setup (name = 'cfunc',
        version = '1.0',
        include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
        ext_modules = [module1])
```

But I don't know how to handle the dependency on fortranfunc.f90.

I'd like this to be platform independent - if that isn't possible, I will look for another solution!  Thank you for all the suggestions so far.

Comment: You might use a C-wrapper for the Fortan-code. Not sure if the two languages are ABI-compatible. I suppose that depends on the target-platform. If the wrapper just forwards all arguments 1:1, this might not even produce actual code.

Comment: Yes, this is possible (I've done it before). The correct approach depends on your compiler and operating system. What compiler flags are you using right now when compiling your C code and your Fortran code?

Comment: Fortran and C interoperability is even in the Standard. See the fortran-iso-c bindings...

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want C in the middle?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: asking me? just a suggestion. However, if the ABI allows, it might just require a C-header and an appropriate Python/C-API module. I just was not sure. Back then, I had something for Pascal which mostly required the functions in the C-header to have he argument list reversed. But that was more than a decade ago.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add information about operaing system and toolchain.

Comment: You forgot about the target platform. Linux? Windows? Amstrad? The more details you give, the better ppl here might help you (sounds logical, doesn't it?;-)

Comment: I did say at the end of the post that I'd like for it to be platform independent - otherwise I'll look for another solution!

Comment: Well, the ABI of C and Fortran might depend on the platform (I detailed that in a comment to one of the answers), however. So, you might really try to find a different solution. One would be to use a Fortran->C converter. I for myself, would first try to find a solution for one system and then try if I can extend this for other, too; for instance using conditional compilation or similar. Anyway, it's your project, so good luck.

Comment: @Olaf The OP clearly says he can call the Fortran routine from his C function, he also provides an example how he does that. The problem is not there, calling Fortran from C is easy. The problem, as I see it, is how to tell Python distutils to compile also the Fortran source or how to tell it where to find the pre-compiled code. I would recommend to switch to Numpy distutils, because they support Fortran http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/distutils.html

Comment: @VladimirF: This information was after the edit which I was done due to my recommendation. Also, he resetricted an answer to portable solutions, which I stated might be problematic (multiple times) and in my last comment I tried to highlight this could barrier the way as the way to a general soulution might be over a specific one. Also, he did not explicitly mention to use a C-wrapper (that was also my suggestion), but left that open. Adding the fortan-library/object to distutils should be not different from adding C-based libs, as these are ELF, and not directly related to the source PL.

Comment: @Olaf C-Fortran interop can be made portably, that is not a problem. The point is that you are adding a source, not a library, so it makes a difference. If you know how to add the compiled library, put it into an answer, that is what the OP is looking for..

Comment: @VladimirF: I did not provide an answer and wished good luck for a reason. I just tried to help him as far as I could without doing his job. While sure you can add a lib, I do not actually know how to exactly and platform-independent (as at least the object files on Win and Linux e.g have different extensions). The latter was a requirement of the OP. Adding the fortran-module as an object/lib was actually an alternative you brought up yourself! (You _do_ know compiled code goes into an object file, do you?).

Comment: And, if that is just a single source file, I don't see much of a problem in calling the compiler explicitly. Only disadvantage is it will be re-compiled on each run. setup.py is actually a Python program, so you are free to do anything you want. People tend to forget about this.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for teaching me. You know you can archive the object files in a static library or make a dynamic library, do you?

Comment: No, just fell down to earth. - sorry, needed that. Sure I do, but what has that to do with this discussion? This is still not dependent on the original PL, but a matter of the run-time. Also, it would certainly be one of the least problems to be limited to either.

Comment: That was a sarcasm @Olaf .

Comment: @VladimirF: No kidding? Wow, missed that completely.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to consider the NumPy's extension to distutils, which brings support for Fortran http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/distutils.html.

Notably, you can include a Fortran source file the same way you do it for the `.c` source file

```
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension, setup

setup(name='hw',
       ext_modules=[Extension(name='hw', sources=['../hw.f'])],
       )
```

according to [Combining Python with Fortran, C and C++](http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~raoulb/teaching/PythonTutorial/combining.html).

Answer (score 0):

generally, you can call any exported function in any OBJ file or LIB, but when it comes to different compilers of different languages , the problems start.

although it is not a standard ,but it's usually that the one language compilers have their  convenience for decorating/mangling external symbols to be used by the linker later. so a function in the c library for example defined in the c source code by the name `"printf"` will be decorated in the object file to be `"_printf"` then when you try to call it from another language compiler, this language compiler might follow a different decoration rule. so when you declare it in your python source code with it's name `"printf"`, the compiler will mangled it to be something else like `_printf_` for instance.

later when the linker tries to resolve external symbols between the C library and your python object file he will find mismatch between  `"_printf"` and `"_printf_"`, which will raise a fatal error and stop building the executable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: Adding a suffix or prefix like `_` was common in the 80ies and partly 90ies, but is not common anymore. So you should relativize your statement. For instance, gcc does not modify external symbols like that anymore (if it ever did in the last - let's say - 15 years). However, expecially for Fortran, this might be possible. But much more problematic would be marshalling of function arguments, register file layout and packing of compound data types. For scalar types, there are mostly simple solutions, as they most times are processed by the hardware.

Comment: Python is an interpreted language; it is not linked like C code. This is about providing a C-module which interfaces between compiled code and Python programs. Python binaries do actually exist, but they are bytecode (similar to Java) and are loaded at run-time. Also, the namespace(s) of the Python code is completely independent from the compiled/linked code.

Answer (score 0):

If the only purpose of the C code is to act as a wrapper to allow you to run the Fortran code in Python then you may be better served by using [f2py](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/) to generate a Python module from the Fortran code directly.

Comment: The bulk of my code is written in C, so unfortunately I can't just call the Fortran from python directly.

Comment: If the functionalities can be seperated, you might create two modules.

Comment: unfortunately they're not -- otherwise that's would I would do!